# AngularJS keep category expanded at where user left off

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to the angularJS. And recently I have been working on a angularJS project. I use the ng-template and ng-repeat to make a multiple product category tree. And I add a button to control whether the sub-category expanded or not.Here is the problem,How I can keep the category expaneded at where user left off when the user click into other pages and click back to the category page?

Comment: Show your code, otherwise it is hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the current tree state into the HTML5 Localstorage. 
Add a unique id to each category and save them into the localstorage.

```
function saveCurrentState() {
    const openedCategories = /*  find the opened categories */;
    // we injected $window in our controller.
    $window.localStorage.setItem('openedCategories', openedCategories.join(','));
}
```

Then, when you load the page

```
/* to be run on the page load.*/
function retrieveOpenedCategories() {
    // all the current categories, open or not.
    const categories = /* get all the categories */;
    // we retrive our category from the localStorage. With some code to handle if it's empty / null.
    const openedCategories = ($window.localStorage.getItem('openedCategories') || "").split(',');
   // check if we have categories that were opened. length of 0 will evaluate to false-y.
   if(openedCategories.length) {
      // we use map because we want to change every value from the original array.
      categories = categories.map((category) => {
          if(openedCategories.includes(category.id)) {
              category.open = true;
          }
          return category;
      }); 
   } 
}

/* we show our categories, somehow.*/
```